# Javascript Whole Numbers

Tags: javascript, operators

How to disregard remainder or decimal values:
Example: `var x = 5/2;`
Result:   `x = 2.5;`
What i want is that whatever decimal value will be disregarded so the final output should be `x = 2;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Math.floor()` (round down), `Math.ceil()` (round up) or `Math.round()` (round to nearest integer), dependening on how you wanted to remove the decimal.

**Example:**

if `x = 2.5`, `Math.floor(x) = 2`, `Math.ceil(x) = 3`, `Math.round(x) = 3`.

**For Reference:**

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BVYDR/

Answer (score 3):

The `|` operator forces its argument to an integral value by rounding towards zero.

```
(3.141592654 | 0) === 3
```

Comment: Tricky, yet it can be slower http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/2

Answer (score 3):

`parseInt(5/2)` will give you `2`